# Edit Items = Edit Pages?

Tags: 2007, permissions

When users have edit permission on a list or library, they can edit the views and forms associated with it. Is there any way to restrict edit permission to ITEMS only? Editing items and editing forms are two very different things, but, SharePoint blows, so...

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, you must have following fine graiened permissions to create and modify public views

Manage Lists  -  Create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list.

This is different permisison than "Edit Items"

Apart from that there is also permission shown below which you can control
Manage Personal Views  -  Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.

I assume same would be true for SP2007.